# Jenkins pipeline plugin: set the build description

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to replace our current build pipeline, currently hacked together using old-school Jenkins jobs, with a new job that uses the Jenkins pipeline plugin, and loads a `Jenkinsfile` from the project repository.

One thing that the legacy job did was set the build description to include the Mercurial hash, username and current version using the [Description setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Project+Description+Setter+Plugin), so that builds are easy to find.

Is there a way to replicate/emulate this behaviour with the Jenkins pipeline plugin?

Comment: There is no way to do it in declarative pipeline. See this q & a: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/220860347-How-to-set-build-name-in-Pipeline-job-

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43639099/357774.

Comment: Now we just need a nice way to get regex matching strings out of the console.log ...

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Just figured it out. The pipeline job exposes a `currentBuild` global variable with writable properties. Setting the description can be done with:

```
currentBuild.description = "my new description"
```

anywhere in the pipeline script. More information in this [DZone tutorial](https://dzone.com/refcardz/continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-workflow).

Comment: To do this in declarative pipeline use the script { ... } block https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script

Comment: @jjst Do you know how to set "Job Description" in pipeline ?

Comment: This not necessarily correct because this is not the way to do it in declarative pipeline. Using a script tag is basically escaping pipeline.

Comment: it's also possible to change the `displayName` too: https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild

Comment: I was trying to update the build number and stumble upon your post on updating description. Wish had seen your post earlier, tried so many things from overriding environment variable BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME to using withEnv. I was able to update the values and even print the new values but on Jenkins UI itself the build number was not getting updated. Tried your solution and it worked like a charm!

Comment: is there some way i cant set this from  ```sh''' '''```

Comment: "This not necessarily correct because this is not the way to do it in declarative pipeline. Using a script tag is basically escaping pipeline."  This is not true at all.  Scripted pipeline and Declarative pipeline are both based on the same underlying framework.  You aren't "escaping" Pipeline at all.  They're both pipeline.  You're escaping the Declarative layer.

Answer (score 43):

The answer from @jjst describes how to set the build description in "scripted pipelines". In declarative pipelines you can do the same, but need to place it inside a `script { }` block. Here a complete working example taken from [a Cloudbees article](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/how-to-set-build-name-in-pipeline-job):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("1st stage") {
            steps {
                script {
                    currentBuild.displayName = "My custom build name"
                    currentBuild.description = "My custom build description"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This may not have been the case when jjst wrote his answer but now with the latest jenkins and plugins you can set this outside the main pipeline at the top. This means you dont have to embed script setting and have special steps etc eg

```
currentBuild.description = "my new description"
pipeline {...
```

or

```
currentBuild.description = """
blah
blah
blah
"""
pipeline {
```

Comment: Does this also work for `currentBuild.displayName`? We are using scripted pipelines, so this doesn't apply to us and I can't test it. I expect others would want to know.

Comment: Could you please specify what version "latest jenkins" meant at the time of your post? We are stuck on 2.138.3 for reasons i don't want to get in to.

Comment: I was using the current version from their ubuntu repo at the time as we tend to auto upgrade and rollback (small team spread to thin) if we find an issue so l would check the release dates.

Comment: You can even use parameters and global environment variables when setting the description/displayName outside of the pipeline. But it doesn't seem to work for variables defined in the pipeline 'environment' block.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how old it is, but I recently discovered the `buildDescription` plugin that gives you a declarative method to set the build description. 
Once installed, it's as easy as:

```
steps {
  buildDescription 'my build'
}
```

The console will show a step output:
`New run description is 'my build'`