# Jenkins change build number

Tags: jenkins

We are in the process of moving our build system over to Jenkins or at least seeing if it is viable. One thing that is currently becoming an issue is our build number or build version. We number our builds and CIs based on the changelist that is polled in source at the time of the build.

So for a CIs we tag it "CI-${CL#}-${branch}" and builds we tag them as "${date}-${CL#}-${branch}" (these are simplified, but gives you an idea what I am doing). Jenkins does its auto increment - 1.2.3. etc.

We are using Pipelines and need to do this during the build. As there are post build/CI things that rely on the build number. I could use a new variable to convey the build version, but when looking at the builds on the different nodes, it would be better to identify the build the way we are used to and have it the same as the build version.

Thanks for any help.
D

Comment: Try this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said you are using pipeline scripting, See [How to set build name in Pipeline job?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/220860347-How-to-set-build-name-in-Pipeline-job-) to help do that. And pasting that code also for quick reference.

```
node {
  currentBuild.displayName = "fooName"
  currentBuild.description = "fooDescription"
}
```

See also [Set the build name and description from a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639099/set-the-build-name-and-description-from-a-jenkins-declarative-pipeline)
 for more info. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I needs. I appreciate the answer.